# What is the smoothest parameters for texturing with multi-sampling mode?

Tags: texture-mapping, smoothing, multisampling

what is the smoothest parameters for texturing with multi-sampling mode.

I mean to say I am using GL_LINEAR, GL_CLAMP, and GL_MODULATE. What should I choose here to get smoothest texture.

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);
```